# PHPExcel sheet lock works perfect in excel other than version 2016

Tags: php, phpexcel, excel-2016

In my website I am using `PHPExcel` for download excel files. I am using **Locking** of sheets and rows.

**The problem is, in `MS Office 2016` the rows which are unlocked is shown as locked. But it happens only for rows after 25th row. That is, the rows are not editable after the 25th row**

I tried google and `PHPExcel` docs for this. But there is no help available. If anyone can solve this issue, it will be a huge help.

**Note:** The version I am using is `PHPExcel 1.7.9`.

Comment: submit bug report at phpexcel

Comment: Suggest you also upgrade to PHPExcel 1.8.1 as well, 1.7.9 is quite an old version

Comment: @MarkBaker, I am a bit late to reply. But your solution is perfect. It solves the issue without change any other code, but just update the version to 1.8.1